# Android - How to clear an ExposedDropdownMenu

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, autocompletetextview

I have an `ExposedDropdownMenu` like this:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/input_layout_models"
    style="@style/Widget.Material3.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu.Honk"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/size_medium"
   
 android:theme="@style/Widget.Material3.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu.Honk"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/input_layout_brands">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/auto_complete_text_models"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/vehicle_model"
            android:inputType="none"
            android:labelFor="@id/input_layout_models" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

And I fill it with elements like this:

```kotlin
private fun onModelsChanged(models: List<Model>) = binding.run {
    (autoCompleteTextModels as? MaterialAutoCompleteTextView)?.setSimpleItems(models
        .map { it.description }
        .toTypedArray()
    )
}
```

And I just want to clear its text. I tried the following:

##### 1 Setting an empty list on my MaterialAutoCompleteTextView

```kotlin
(autoCompleteTextModels as? MaterialAutoCompleteTextView)?.setSimpleItems(
    emptyList<Model>().map { it.description }.toTypedArray()
)
```

##### 2 Setting an empty text on my AutoCompleteTextView

```kotlin
autoCompleteTextModels.setText("")
```

##### 3 Setting an empty text on my TextInputLayout

```kotlin
modelYearInput.setText("")
```

##### 4 Clearing the editableText from my AutoCompleteTextView

```kotlin
(autoCompleteTextModels as? MaterialAutoCompleteTextView)?.editableText?.clear()
```

But nothing worked. Any idea on how I can achieve this?

I'm using this version of the Material Library:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
```

Comment: Is `setSimpleItems()` for data binding? or is it an extension function? can you show it

Comment: @Zain Thanks for helping . This is a function from MaterialAutoCompleteTextView, a native android View> I will also put the version of the material library I'm using.

Comment: Sorry as I tested it on the normal ACTV not the material one; I will check if I can re-answer it

Comment: Can you also check if something continously feeds this list like a liveData or flow that overides the clearance behavior

Comment: @Zain The flow was the problem! I fixed it and changed your answer to what made it work

Comment: Thanks for that modification, I thought that something else rather than resetting the list is causing that. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have some livedata, stateflow or similar altering your UI, because:

This should clear the text on your `AutoCompleteTextView`:

```kotlin
autoCompleteTextModels.setText("")
```

This should clear it's list:

```kotlin
(autoCompleteTextModels as? MaterialAutoCompleteTextView)?.setSimpleItems(emptyList()))
```

---

One alternative by having a null adapter:

```
autoCompleteTextModels.setAdapter(null)
```

Another alternative with an empty list:

```
(autoCompleteTextModels as? MaterialAutoCompleteTextView)?.setSimpleItems(
    emptyArray<String>()
        .map { it }
        .toTypedArray()
)
```

Comment: This unfortunatlly does not work

Comment: @LeonardodeOliveiraSibela Please have a look to the edited answer; I've tried that on the material thing

Comment: it worked! I changed your answer a little to reflect what I did. Thank you very much